# I can't manage to compile Qt + PortAudio sur Qt

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, portaudio

I am trying to compile Qt + PortAudio on Visual Studio 2010. I made a new Makefile project in visual (Visual C++/General/Makefile project). I am getting this error:

> Error 8   error MSB3073: The command "qmake & nmake" exited with code 2.  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets    38  6   my_babel
>
> Error 7   error U1077: 'c:\Qt\4.7.4\bin\qmake.exe' : return code '0x2'    c:\Users\Ju\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\my_babel\my_babel\NMAKE   my_babel

Comment: What does it mean compile Qt + Portaudio? Do you mean an application written using both Qt and Portaudio for accessing audio hardware?

Comment: If there is a problem with your Makefile (what is this my_babel?) then show it to us.

Comment: Yes i want to use QT and Portaudio.
The problem seems to be in Visual Studio 2010, i can compile a simple QT Project without error, but when i link portaudio i can't manage to run the binary...

Comment: did you tried to compile it using visual studio 2010 command line tools ?